# how to compare two hashmap/hashtable to find only unique key

Tags: java

```
Hashtable h1=new Hashtable<>();
    h1.put(1, "abc");
    h1.put(2, "xyz");
    h1.put(26, "jhd");


    Hashtable h2=new Hashtable<>();
    h2.put(1, "da");
    h2.put(2, "bfdsae");
    h2.put(8, "sdasd");

    Hashtable h3= new Hashtable<>();
     below two output musst add in h3.
```

expected O/P
is:-
8, "sdasd"
26, "jhd"
when i will compare two hashtable to each other above required output has to be produced.

Comment: Add everything in from h1 in h3. Then copy h2 to h3; but if entry exists in h3 remove it.

Comment: how can we implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Using [google guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/23.0) you could get this with [`Maps.difference`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference-java.util.Map-java.util.Map-):

```
MapDifference<Integer, String> difference = Maps.difference(h1, h2);

h3.putAll(difference.entriesOnlyOnLeft());
h3.putAll(difference.entriesOnlyOnRight());
```

It gives you `{8=sdasd, 26=jhd}` in `h3`

Answer (score 0):

Traverse h1 and check if the exists in h2, if it doesn't,then put in h3.
Similarly, Traverse h2 and check if the exists in h1, if it doesn't,then put in h3.

```
    Hashtable h1=new Hashtable<>();
        h1.put(1, "abc");
        h1.put(2, "xyz");
        h1.put(26, "jhd");


        Hashtable h2=new Hashtable<>();
        h2.put(1, "da");
        h2.put(2, "bfdsae");
        h2.put(8, "sdasd");

        Hashtable h3= new Hashtable<>();
        Set<String> keys = h1.keySet();
        for(String k: keys){
            if(!h2.containsKey(k)) {
                h3.put(k, h1.get(k));
            }
        }
        Set<String> keysH2 = h2.keySet();
        for(String k: keys){
            if(!h1.containsKey(k)) {
                h3.put(k, h2.get(k));
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is exactly i want could you please help me with code

Comment: i want to show all h3 data in data grid how can  i do that

Comment: how can we compare key and value in above code.if any one know please send me modified code